# iText GetTextFromPage exception with inline image

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have the same problem as was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399947), which was not solved. My objective is to extract the text from an existing pdf file. I get the error message `Could not find image data or EI` for a certain pdf, which I cannot share as a sample. It works for other pdfs, with the following code

```
string fileURI = "C:\\Test\\Sample.pdf";
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileURI);
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
string s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, strategy);
Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

I am using iTextSharp 5.5.0 and tried changing `found == 1` to `found <= 1` as suggested in other posts. It does not help.

Would it help to remove all images in the pdf? I really just need the text. Which commands from iText could help me with this?

Comment: *for a certain pdf, which I cannot share* - As neither you nor the person who asked the question you referred to is willing to provide a sample PDF, you will likely have to fix the issue yourself or wait until someone with the same issue comes along and shares his file. You might consider asking iText staff whether there is some way for you to provide the PDF with limited leakage only.

Comment: As mkl said, we can't help you if you won't/can't share your PDF. If the PDF contains confidential data (and if you _really_ can't share it), try creating a PDF with dummy data that reproduces this problem.

Comment: Could be due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167231/probable-bug-in-itextsharp-parser-re-inline-image-handling

Comment: Not sure, your question is about image extraction and this question is about text extraction.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse BUT the exception received says 'could not find IMAGE DATA or EI' (EI is the End Image tag) so the attempt to extract the text is hitting a problem with an inline image - and that's why it could well relate to image parsing. It is possible, even probable to have text and images in the same stream.

Comment: Anyway. Your other question looks well documented. Let's take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the trial version of Acrobat to create a version of the pdf file, that I could share. After opening the file and saving it again as "Optimized PDF" over the Acrobat, the code was working and I could extract the text.

So the solution to the problem is probably opening each file in Acrobat and saving it again with the right settings using the Acrobat reference and then extracting the text.